# Using semantic UI to create a web app layout with a side nav, fixed header, fixed footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui, css-frameworks

I am trying to create a specific site layout for a web application using semantic ui and can't get it down for some reason.

The layout consists of the following pieces:

Sidebar (Narrow sidebar that has a menu icon at the top for making wider/narrow, additionally icons for the primary sections of site, when menu icon is clicked sidebar gets wider, labels appear near icons and everything to the right gets pushed over).

Main Header (This is basically a semantic ui menu, with a logo as the first item)

Sub Header (this is another horizontal bar that will display text and action icons, guessing I can use menu again)

Content (this is will be where the actual content goes, will be the only thing that is scrollable, rest of page should never scroll).

Footer (this will be fixed at the bottom of page, once again can probably use menu)

**Please see image:**
[image]

I have spent a lot of time trying to build this layout with Semantic UI documentation and can't figure it out. I am tempted to do away with using Semantic UI for the site layout, but I love the sidebar functionality.

Comment: Please explain what is not working and what you have tried. The question is too broad.

Comment: How broad? he just explained he wants to achieve the layout in the figure above but the documentation he's referred to didn't help him.